# SSL certs for conda, yarn, npm broken, but pip works

Tags: python, ssl, npm, pip, anaconda

conda, yarn, and npm all fail to install new packages with SSL cert errors.  For conda, the error comes from urllib3 and says things like "bad handshake", "certificate verify failed".  The npm and yarn errors say similar things.  I'm using Windows 10.

I am able to download and install packages by turning off SSL verification for each package manager.

I've found similar questions and answers, but the catch for me is: pip works fine, and installs packages without any problems.  Since I'm behind a corporate network, I wonder if pip was configured along with the browsers to be able to work.

How do I find out how pip is doing SSL verification and configure the other package managers to use the same cert files?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Whoops, windows 10.  Edited the Q